# Function initialization to retrieve stored value when called

Tags: javascript

I want to store an array in a Javscript function, to retrieve the value stored when called after initialized

I tried this:

```
function myFunc() {
  this.myArr = [];

  function init() {
    if (myArr.lenght === 0) {
      myArr.push(1);
      myArr.push(2);
      myArr.push(3);
      console.log("initialized now");
    } else {
      console.log("initialized already. Arrlength: ", myArr.lenght);
    }
  }

  return myArr;
}

myFunc.init()

console.log(myFunc());
```

Expected output:

initialized now
initialized already. Arrlength: 3

Obtained output:
TypeError: myFunc.init is not a function

Comment: Well, that's just not how that works. `myFunc` would need to be an *object* with a *property* `init`. Which it isn't.

Comment: probably something like https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/ ?

Comment: @davidhu I am asking this for the specific case of Javascript and functions, not for typescript and classes. Thanks for your sugggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are trying to achieve but it's working:

```
function myFunc() {
  myArr = [];
  function init() {
    if (myArr.length === 0) {
      myArr.push(1);
      myArr.push(2);
      myArr.push(3);
      console.log("initialized now");
    } else {
      console.log("initialized already. Arrlength: ", myArr.length);
    }
  }
  
  function getArr() {
    return myArr;
  }
  
  myFunc.init = init;
  myFunc.getArr = getArr;
}

myFunc();
myFunc.init();
console.log(myFunc.getArr()); // output: Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't want to use `class` you always go back to the prototype method where you create a constructor function (note: `class` is just syntactic sugar over this prototype method and maybe easier to understand in the long-run).

```js
// Constructor. Set the array to null
function Example() {
  this.arr = null;
}

// `init` can accept an array argument
// If there is an array, set `this.arr` to it
// otherwise use the default array
Example.prototype.init = function(arr) {
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    this.arr = arr;
    return `Initialized now. length: ${this.arr.length}`;
  } else {
    this.arr = [1, 2, 3];
    return `Initialized already. length: ${this.arr.length}`;
  }
}

// Not passing in an array so we use
// the default array
const instance = new Example();
console.log(instance.init());

// Passing in an array that gets assigned
const instance2 = new Example();
console.log(instance2.init([1]));
```

Comment: That one's better in the case, actually.

Comment: But really, all that `init` stuff should be part of the constructor, or it should be a static method that returns a differently initialised object as alternative to `new`…

Comment: :) Can you point to something that would help me understand what you just said @deceze. I didn't realise there was an alternative to `new`.

Comment: I mean, design the class/constructor function such that you do either `new Example(...)`, *or* `Example.init()`, and both would return an instance. The `init` version would internally do something like `return new this(...)`. — This is because constructors should always be required to be run first, so you simply can't have an object in some weird uninitialised state.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `myFunc.init` is invalid; `myFunc` is a function not an *object*.

You can try this:

```js
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.myArr = [1];
    }

    init() {
        if (this.myArr.length === 0) {
            this.myArr.push(1);
            this.myArr.push(2);
            this.myArr.push(3);
            console.log("initialized now");
        } else {
            console.log("initialized already. Arrlength: ", this.myArr.length);
        }
    }
}

new Something().init() // would give desired results.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I wanted to used functions without the class keyword